# Change style of multiple specific elements on hover at a specific element

Tags: html, css

How can I change the style of different elements on hover at a specific element?

E.g. there are multiple divs, and you want to change the style of some of them to unique individual styles, if the mouse hovers over a specific div.

```css
.standard {
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height:60px;
    width:60px;
    margin:4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="standard" id="master"><center>HOVER HERE</center></div>
<div class="standard" id="element"><center>1</center></div>
<div class="standard" id="another_element"><center>2</center></div>
<div class="standard yet_another_element"><center>3</center></div>
```

Please run the example.
How can I change different style attributes of `another_element` and `yet_another_element`, (e.g. the `background-color`) if the user hovers over the element with id `master`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does only work, if the elements which you try to manipulate, are child elements of the element on which you are hovering (`master`).

Then you can use CSS code like this to access and manipulate these elements:

**By using ID**

```
#master:hover #another_element {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

**By using Class**

```
#master:hover .yet_another_element {
    background-color: red;
}
```

---

### Example

```css
/* --- By using ID --- */
#master:hover #another_element {
    background-color: orange;
}

/* --- By using Class --- */
#master:hover .yet_another_element {
    background-color: red;
}


/*--- Irrelevant CSS Code...---*/
.standard {
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height:60px;
    width:60px;
    margin:4px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#element {
  background-color: green;
}

#master {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
```

```html
<div id="master">
    <center>hover here</center>
    <div class="standard" id="element"><center>1</center></div>
    <div class="standard" id="another_element"><center>2</center></div>
    <div class="standard yet_another_element"><center>3</center></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, in the case you posted, you can just use the [General Sibling Combinator(`~`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#Combinators):

```css
.standard {
  background-color: #D8D8D8;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 4px;
}
#master:hover,
#master:hover ~ .standard {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="standard" id="master">
  <center>HOVER HERE</center>
</div>
<div class="standard" id="element">
  <center>1</center>
</div>
<div class="standard" id="another_element">
  <center>2</center>
</div>
<div class="standard" id="yet_another_element">
  <center>3</center>
</div>
```

If you want to have different styles for different elements, as you noted in the comments, just select them:

```css
.standard {
  background-color: #D8D8D8;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 4px;
}
#master:hover {
  background: red;
}
#master:hover ~ #element {
  background: blue;
}
#master:hover ~ #another_element {
  background: purple;
}
#master:hover ~ #yet_another_element {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="standard" id="master">
  <center>HOVER HERE</center>
</div>
<div class="standard" id="element">
  <center>1</center>
</div>
<div class="standard" id="another_element">
  <center>2</center>
</div>
<div class="standard" id="yet_another_element">
  <center>3</center>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice thx :) but what If i try to change the background-color of `yet_another_element` to red and the background-color from `another_element` to orange? Then i guess it won't work with your method?

Comment: @EdwardBlack nope, you can still do it, just takes a bit more complex of a selector: https://jsfiddle.net/03tsytLL/ (using SCSS)

Comment: Ye but SCSS need to be compiled, isn't it?

Comment: @EdwardBlack that's just so I don't have to write a bit more. I posted a CSS version in my answer that does the same thing

Answer (score 1):

```css
#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}


    
.description {
  height: 30px;
  background:#333; 
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-family: open sans, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
    
li:hover .thumbnail { 
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: pointer;

}
    
li:hover .description {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<div id="container">
  
<ul>
  <li>
      <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" /></div>
      <div class="description">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  
  </li>
  
   <li>
        <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" /></div>
        <div class="description">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    </li>
  
</ul>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like...

```
.standard {
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height:60px;
    width:60px;
    margin:4px;
}
#master:hover ~ #another_element, #master:hover ~ .yet_another_element {
  background:red;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/MohdAbdulMujib/pen/XjQryy)**

Since we want specific elements to be affected, we will have to target individual elements while writing the rules.